# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'paginate' error has occurred

Tags: python, flask

```
def getRoomKeepList(page=None, per_page=None, is_reserved=None, is_in_used=None, is_ended=None, sort_key=None, is_asc=None, shop_id=None, room_id=None, keep_room_id=None, memo=None, room_number=None, user=None, token_info=None):
    """
    get_keep_room_list
    """

    # if keep_room_id and shop_id:
    if shop_id:
        keepRooms = (
            db.session.query(M_keep_room, M_shop.name, M_room_type, M_shop.shop_id, M_room)
            .join(M_room, M_keep_room.room_id == M_room.room_id)
            .join(M_shop, M_room.shop_id == M_shop.shop_id)
            .join(M_room_type, M_room.room_type_id == M_room_type.room_type_id)
            .filter(
                M_room.is_deleted == False,
                M_keep_room.is_deleted == False,
                M_shop.is_deleted == False,
                # M_keep_room.keep_room_id == keep_room_id,
                M_shop.shop_id == shop_id,
            )
        )
    else:
        keepRooms = (
        # query = (
            db.session.query(M_keep_room, M_shop.name, M_room_type, M_shop.shop_id, M_room)
            .join(M_room, M_keep_room.room_id == M_room.room_id)
            .join(M_shop, M_room.shop_id == M_shop.shop_id)
            .join(M_room_type, M_room.room_type_id == M_room_type.room_type_id)
            .filter(
                M_room.is_deleted == False,
                M_keep_room.is_deleted == False,
                M_shop.is_deleted == False,
            )
        )


    # sort
    if sort_key == 'use_start_date':
        if is_asc:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.keep_start_date.asc()).all()
        else:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.keep_start_date.desc()).all()

    if sort_key == 'use_end_date':
        if is_asc:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.keep_end_date.asc()).all()
        else:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.keep_end_date.desc()).all()

    if sort_key == 'create_date':
        if is_asc:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.created_at.asc()).all()
        else:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.created_at.desc()).all()

    if sort_key == 'last_update_at':
        if is_asc:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.updated_at.asc()).all()
        else:
            keepRooms = keepRooms.order_by(M_keep_room.updated_at.desc()).all()

    
    if keepRooms:
        keepRoomList = keepRooms.paginate(page, per_page, error_out=False)
        return [
            KeepRoomList(
                keep_room_id=keepRoom[0].keep_room_id,
                room_id=keepRoom[0].room_id,
                start_date=keepRoom[0].keep_start_date.isoformat(),
                end_date=keepRoom[0].keep_end_date.isoformat(),
                keep_memo=keepRoom[0].memo,
                last_update_at=keepRoom[0].updated_at,
                created_at=keepRoom[0].created_at,
                shop_name=keepRoom[1],  # 店舗名
                room_short_type=keepRoom[2].room_short_type,
                room_type=keepRoom[2].room_type,
                shop_id=keepRoom[3],  # 部屋のID
                room_number=keepRoom[4].room_number, 
                # room_type=keepRoom[4].room_type,  
                room_type_id=keepRoom[4].room_type_id, 
            )
            for keepRoom in keepRoomList.items
        ]
    else:
        return None
```

I use Flask.
In the above section `keepRoomList = keepRooms.paginate(page, per_page, error_out=False)`, I got the error which says `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'paginate'` error has occurred.

What should I do?

```
        # start = (page - 1) * per_page
        # end = start + per_page
        # keepRoomList = keepRooms[start:end]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: But please start by trying to think logically about the code. Where it says `keepRoomList = keepRooms.paginate(page, per_page, error_out=False)`, what do you think this should mean, step by step? Before this line runs, what do you think is in `keepRooms`? Does it make sense to use `paginate` with that? Why? What do you think should happen as a result? Did you try to check, to make sure that `keepRooms` is what you expect?